# Async Action and Future

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework

I'm using Play 2.5 and Scala 2.11.  I'm trying to use async Action with Future to return json string but can't get it to work.
Here is my action :

```
def getData = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val futureData = Future { daoObj.fetchData }
    futureData onComplete {
        case Success(data) =>
            Ok(Json.prettyPrint(Json.obj("data" -> data.groupBy(_.name))))
        case Failure(t) => 
            BadRequest(Json.prettyPrint(Json.obj(
                "status" -> "400",
                "message" -> s"$t"
            )))
    }
}
```

The daoObj.fetchData returns scala.concurrent.Future[List[models.Data]]

Here is the models.Data :

```
case class Data(name: String, details: String)
```

I can have data like this

```
Data (name = "data1", details = "details1")
Data (name = "data1", details = "details1a")
Data (name = "data2", details = "details2")
```

that I can join on name to return a structure of the form

```
Map(data1 -> List("details1", "details11"),
    data2 -> List("details2"))
```

I have a compilation error on groupBy :

```
value groupBy is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[List[models.Data]]
```

1) How to get the value (List[models.Data]) from the Future in my action ?

2) It's my first Play Scala app so if you have any comment to improve my code, it's welcome.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `Future{}` around `daoObj.fetchData`. Remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `Future.onComplete`, which is a callback (with side-effect), but `.map` and `.recover` to turn your `Future[T]` into a `Future[Result]` which is what's expected by `Action.async`.

```
def getData = Action.async { implicit request =>
  Future { daoObj.fetchData }.map { data =>
    Json.obj("data" -> data.groupBy(_.name))
  }.recover {
    case error => BadRequest(Json.obj(
      "status" -> "400",
      "message" -> error.getMessage
    ))
  }
}
```

> There is no need to pretty-print the `JsObject` which can be directly written as result (except for debugging purposes maybe).